# Divide a data.table into sub-tables conditionally to column values

Tags: r, split, data.table

This question is related to `data.table` class, from the homonymous `R` package.

Given a `data.table` object I would like to divide it into slices according to the values ​​of some of its columns.

To make clear what I must do I give an example.

Suppose this is the input `data.table`.

```
dataf <- data.frame(list(
  T = c(1.80,1.81,1.82,1.83,1.85,1.87,1.90,1.95,2.00),
  A = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0),
  B = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
  C = c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0),
  D = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0))
)
datat <- data.table(dataf)
datat
#       T A B C D
# 1: 1.80 1 0 0 0
# 2: 1.81 0 0 1 0
# 3: 1.82 1 0 0 1
# 4: 1.83 1 0 1 1
# 5: 1.85 1 0 1 1
# 6: 1.87 0 0 0 0
# 7: 1.90 1 1 1 0
# 8: 1.95 1 0 1 1
# 9: 2.00 0 0 0 0
```

The **goal** is to split this table into sub-tables, based on the values ​​of `n` selected columns (with `n = 0, ..., ncol(datat) - 1`).

For this input, selecting as anchor columns `C` and `D`, the output have to be something like:

```
# $`0|0`
#       T A B C D
# 1: 1.80 1 0 0 0

# $`1|0`
#       T A B C D
# 1: 1.81 0 0 1 0

# $`0|1`
#       T A B C D
# 1: 1.82 1 0 0 1

# $`1|1`
#       T A B C D
# 1: 1.83 1 0 1 1
# 2: 1.85 1 0 1 1

# $`0|0`
#       T A B C D
# 1: 1.87 0 0 0 0

# $`1|0`
#       T A B C D
# 1: 1.90 1 1 1 0

# $`1|1`
#       T A B C D
# 1: 1.95 1 0 1 1

# $`0|0`
#       T A B C D
# 1: 2.00 0 0 0 0
```

As deducible from the example just shown, **the splitting condition** is:

- the value of the selected columns is different from its value in the previous line?

*Important*: in this example the word "value" has to be intended as the couple of column values.

*Note*:

I thought to this output structure as then (the second **goal**) I have to apply one (or two) function to this sub-tables, get their outputs and aggregate them (e.g. sum, merge or other operations) by the common name of the element list (i.e. `0|0` with `0|0`, `1|0` with `1|0` etc. etc.).

If you think that there is a better fitted or easier output structure that will permit also this second goal, your suggests are very welcome.

Obiviously, the performances of the solution are important because I have to process big tables.

Unfortunately, I consider myself a newbie with `data.table` package, infact I know only few things about it: how to subset by colnames, etc. etc..

So your help is greatly appreciated, as it will help me to learn something new. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it with `rle` and `split` as follows:

```
ids <- do.call(paste, c(datat[, 4:5], sep="|"))
rle.ids <- rle(ids)
datat.spl <- split(datat, rep(seq_along(rle.ids$values), rle.ids$lengths))
names(datat.spl) <- rle.ids$values
```

---

Reading your note section, since your objective is to *apply functions* to these sub tables by *grouping/aggregating* them, I'd suggest just adding an additional column to `data.table` like so:

```
datat[, grp1 := do.call(paste, c(datat[, 4:5], sep="|"))]
```

If you want you can also add another grouping like so:

```
datat[, grp2 := rep(seq_along(rle.ids$values), rle.ids$lengths)]
```

Now if you want all the "0|0" grouped together, then subset by `grp1`.

```
# example
datat[, list(s.A = sum(A)), by = grp1]
```

If you want the aggregation to be done for every separate set of "0|0", then, subset by `grp2`.

```
# example
datat[, list(grp1 = grp1[1], s.A = sum(A)), by = grp2]
```

Hope this helps.